# Prove that cl(int(cl(int(A)))) = cl(int(A))

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am suppose to show that

$ cl(int(cl(int(A)))) = cl(int(A)) $

and also that

$int(cl(int(cl(A)))) = int(cl(A)) $

and  I am having problems doing that becuse i just cannot figure out were to start. So any help is great.

Comment: $A$ is a subset of the real numbers?

Comment: Yes A is subset in real numbers

Comment: http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/24.pdf, proposition p (or p') and q. Works in all spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to use $kA$ for the closure of $A$, and $iA$ for the interior of $A$.  The following facts are needed
$$A\subseteq kA\\iA\subseteq A\\kkA=kA\\iiA=iA\\A\subseteq B\implies kA\subseteq kB\\A\subseteq B\implies iA\subseteq iB$$

If you haven't been presented with these you should prove them for yourself.

So, one strategy here is to show $kikiA\subseteq kiA$ and $kiA\subseteq kikiA$.

Here is one direction,
$$\begin{align}
iA\subseteq A & \implies kiA\subseteq kA\\
& \implies kikA\subseteq kk A,\quad\text{replacing } A\text{ with }kA\\
& \implies kik A\subseteq kA\\
& \implies kiki A\subseteq kiA,\quad\text{replacing } A\text{ with } iA.
\end{align}$$

I leave you to prove the other direction.

Comment: I think you mean $kkA=kA$ and $iiA=iA$.

Comment: Yes, looks like a few things I have to edit.

Comment: Last inclusion has a typo. Should be $kiA$ on the right.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: Why are those replacements valid (steps 2 and 4)?