# Closure of a regular closed set in a dense subspace is regular closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $D$ be a dense subspace in $X.$
If $A$ is a regular closed subset in $D$, then $cl_{X}A$ is also regular
closed subset in $X$. How can I prove this?

Note: A regular closed set is that $cl\left( int\left( A\right)
\right) =A$.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is that:

Since $A=cl_{D}\left( Int_{D}\left( A\right) \right) $, then there exist an
open subset $U$ in $X$ such that $Int_{D}\left( A\right) =U\cap D$. Hence $%
A=cl_{D}\left( U\cap D\right) =cl_{X}\left( U\cap D\right) \cap
D=cl_{X}\left( U\right) \cap D$. Therefore, since $U$ is an open set in $X$,
then $cl_{X}\left( U\right) $ is a regular closed set in $X$. Claim that $%
cl_{X}\left( U\right) =cl_{X}\left( A\right) $. Since $A\subset cl_{X}\left(
U\right) $, it is clearly that $cl_{X}\left( A\right) \subset cl_{X}\left(
U\right) $. Conversely, assume that $a\in cl_{X}\left( U\right) $ and $W$ is
an open neighborhood of $a$ in $X$. Then $W\cap U\neq \emptyset $ and since $%
D$ is dense in $X$, so $W\cap U\cap D\neq \emptyset $ and $W\cap
cl_{X}\left( U\right) \cap D\neq \emptyset $. Hence $W\cap A\neq \emptyset $, so $a\in cl_{X}\left( A\right) $. Thus $cl_{X}\left( U\right) \subset
cl_{X}\left( A\right) $. Consequently $cl_{X}\left( A\right) =cl_{X}\left(
U\right) $ is regular closed.

Comment: Nice proof, for sure more concise than mine, lol.

Comment: @StefanNicolaePaicu Closure of an open set is always regular closed, because if $U$ is an open set, then  $cl(Int(cl(U)))=cl(Int(cl(Int(U))))=cl(Int(U))=clU$.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623594/prove-that-clintclinta-clinta