# Prove that $\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(X)^c)^c)^c)^c=\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(X)^c)^c$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> $S$ is a metric space and $X \subset S$.
>
> Define $\mathrm{Cl}(X)$ and $X^c$ as the closure and complement of $X$.
>
> Prove that $\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(X)^c)^c)^c)^c=\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(X)^c)^c$

Set $Y=\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(X)^c)^c$ and Y is an open set.So we just need to prove that $$\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(Y)^c)^c=Y$$

And we know that $\mathrm{Cl}(X^C)^C=\mathrm{Int}X$,so we need to prove that
$$\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Int} Y^c)=Y^c$$ and $Y^c$  is a close set.

But there's a problem that I have met,which is that if $Y^c$ with isoloted points,the equation above might be wrong.I guess I dont fully use the conditions of $Y=\mathrm{Cl}(\mathrm{Cl}(X)^c)^c$ to make it wrong.
Appreciate your idea!

Comment: All those closures and complements could make the problem hard to read. To make notation easier, define a function $F$ on the set of subsets of $S$ where $F(X)$ is the complement of the closure of $X$. Then, the problem asks to show that $F \circ F \circ F \circ F=F \circ F$, i.e., $F \circ F$ is idempotent.

Comment: When $F$ is a set function with the properties $X\subseteq F(F(X))$ and $X\subseteq Y$ implies $F(Y)\subseteq F(X)$, then one can prove $F^3=F$ using just those properties. That is sometimes enough for a solution but *unfortunately* $F(F(X))$ does not always contain $X$ in this case :(

Comment: *In my opinion, let...* A proof is no place for opinions.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang@rschwieb
 Thank both of you for suggestions, I have edited it now for ambiguous and inaccurate expression .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$. We follow
John Kelley and denote the complement of $A$, the interior of $A$,
and the closure of $A$ by $A^{\sim}$, $A^{o}$, and $A^{-}$ respectively.

It is well-known that $A^{--}=A^{-}$ (idempotent rule for closure)
and $A^{o}=A^{\sim-\sim}$, $A^{-}=A^{\sim o\sim}$ (duality between
interior and closure). From which you may be able to prove your claim.

Comment: Here, $A^{\sim o\sim}$ means $\left((A^{\sim})^{o}\right)^{\sim}$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.By fully using the $A^{\sim{-}\sim}=A^o$,we can get $A^{o-o-}=A^{o-}$,which is the same thing in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623594/prove-that-clintclinta-clinta).